# How to show ggplot Output in Shiny using source()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a Shiny application and an R Script that I'd like to embed into my Shiny app.  The script outputs a `ggplot` and I am not sure how to make it appear in my Shiny App.  I've excluded some of the extraneous code.  The script is successfully called, and the variables are stored in my workspace, but then nothing is displayed.

I've included the following in my `server.R` file:

```
##server.R##
source("heatmap.R", local=TRUE)

output$heatmap <- renderPlot ({
heatmapOutput
})

##ui.R##
shinyUI(fluidPage(
column(10, plotOutput("heatmap"))
      ),
```

Comment: Did you try saving the ggplot to a variable and passing it to the renderplot function?

Comment: If I save the plot to `heatmapOutput` in `heatmap.R`, and call it as I did in the revised code, would that work?

Comment: I would put the `output$heatmap <- renderPlot ({ all of your code making heatmapOutput })` inside of your "heatmap.R" as well.  Then, just source as you have in server, and there is no need to rewrite the `output$heatmap <- ...`

Answer (score 1):

Your `output` must be inside a `shinyServer`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$heatmap <- renderPlot ({ heatmapOutput })
}
```

Comment: I have it inside of `shinyServer` but nothing is showing up.  Can I just copy and paste the code directly into my Shiny App?

Comment: I solved this by explicitly pasting the `ggplot` code into the `output$heatmap` and it works because all of the variables were successfully loaded.